# how to add onload to span

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function called loadXMLDoc which takes text from the url parameter and sets it inside the parameter name of another page that has the same span name. im trying to use onload to make it into one line by using onload instead of having it in 2 lines.

```html
<span id="span number1" onload="loadXMLDoc('www.url.com','span number1')"></span>
```

```html
<span id="span number1"></span>
<script> loadXMLDoc("www.url.com","span number1");</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible. `onload` works only on external resources (images, frames, ...) and the body itself.

Depending on your page structure you could add  `onload="loadXMLDoc('www.url.com','span number1')"` to the `<body>` tag. Otherwise your second example looks correct and should also work.

Comment: Where can I find the complete list of objects that support onload? or some property to trigger async updates per object? Like item availability.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp